# How to convert a json response to array javascript

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have this json response from a api:

```
[
{
"obj_Id": 66,
"obj_Nombre": "mnu_mantenimiento_de_unidades",
"obj_Descripcion": "Menu de acceso a Mantenimiento de Unidades"
},
{
"obj_Id": 67,
"obj_Nombre": "mnu_vehiculos_en_reparacion",
"obj_Descripcion": "Menu de acceso a Reparacion de Unidades"
},
{
"obj_Id": 68,
"obj_Nombre": "mnu_RTO",
"obj_Descripcion": "Menu de acceso a RTO"
}
]
```

I have this function to make the request and convert the response:

```
async obtenerPermisos() {
      var respuesta = "";
    
      var obj = {
        idUsuario: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("Codigo")),
        contraseña: this.passwordEncriptado,
      };

      this.url = this.urlBase + "usuario/obtenerPermisos";

      respuesta = await this.$http.post(this.url, obj).then((response) => {
        const respuesta1 = JSON.parse(respuesta);
        sessionStorage.setItem("Permisos", respuesta1);
        response.data;
      });

      console.log("Los permisos del usuario son: ");
      console.log(respuesta);
      console.log("El tipo de parametro es: " + typeof respuesta);

      
      sessionStorage.setItem("Permisos", respuesta);
      this.$router.push({ name: "sideBar" });
      location.reload();
    },
```

but i get this error:

[image]

how can i resolve it?

Comment: What is `response.data;` doing? Are you sure you don't need to return it?

Comment: Shouldn't `JSON.parse(respuesta)` be `JSON.parse(response)`?

Comment: Barmar, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The data being returned is not being passed to JSON.parse()

```js
// Wrong implementation
const respuesta1 = JSON.parse(respuesta);

// Correct implementation
const respuesta1 = JSON.parse(response.data);
```

Comment: If `response.data` is already JSON, there's no need for `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: yeah that's true but it's not clear from the code snippet for the question asked